# How to set up an import to WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Is it possible to set up import in WebStorm, so that import from libraries is at the top of the list, and import from my modules at the bottom?

Example

```
import moment from 'moment';
import React from 'react';

import myModule from 'components/...'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable sorting the imports by the module name – that way all the application imports that start with `./` will go after the imports from `node_modules`. This option is available in **Preferences | Editor | Code Style | JavaScript | Imports**, **Sort imports by modules**.

For advanced imports sorting/grouping support, please vote for [WEB-21182](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21182)

Comment: I use absolute paths

Comment: then no, it's not possible. Please vote for WEB-21182 to be notified on any progress with it